# Load custom template from MENU_CALLBACK

Tags: routes, hooks, theming

Here's my current situation: I have an external authentication platform that loads in Drupal via an iframe. When the user is authenticated, the external application redirects the user to a Drupal endpoint I set up using:

```
function mymodule_menu() {

    $items['mymodule/oauth'] = array(
        'title' => 'My Module Receiver',
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_oauth',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'file' => 'mymodule.pages.inc'
    );

    return $items;
}
```

And then my callback:

```
function myapp_oauth() {

    // Does some stuff, authenticates the user, etc

    echo '
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<body>
<p>Please wait...</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Check if we are in an iframe or not
  if (window.location.href != window.parent.location.href) {
    // Reload the parent page
    window.parent.location.reload();
  } else {
    // Not in an iframe, so go to the home page
    window.location.href = "' . base_path() . '";
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
';
    exit;

}
```

This seems like an incredibly sloppy way to handle this to me, I would prefer not to have to exit the application, and ideally I would want to simply define a tpl template file to load in place of the theme files for this page. Can someone recommend a better way to handle this?

Comment: To which Drupal version are you interested?

Comment: I'll need to do it with both 6 & 7, but right now I'm on 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a theme function that uses a template file, and then use theme function to for the menu callback output.
The following is example code for Drupal 7; similar code can be used for Drupal 6.

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_oath' => array(
      'variables' => array('id' => NULL), // This is the list of the variables that will be passed to the template file. 
      'template' => 'mymodule_oath', // Change this to the template file name.
    ),
  );
}

function mymodule_oath() {
  // Does some stuff, authenticates the user, etc.

  print theme('mymodule_oath', array('id' => 10));
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be almost what I'm looking for. I got the template to load, but in the context of the theme. Since I'm looking to do is display template contents that contain javascript that will display a message and close the iframe, so I don't want the theme wrapper.

Comment: @bhamrick I have updated the answer. Returning `NULL` will cause Drupal 7 to not call [drupal_render_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render_page/7).

Comment: If anyone is looking at this, wondering how to get the template to load in the context of the theme (like I was), I got it to work using `return theme('mymodule_oath'...`  instead of  `print theme('mymodule_oath'...`

Answer (score 1):

If you return false from your menu handler, Drupal will not call `page.tpl.php`.

So:

```
function myapp_oath() {
    // Echo your page here
    return false;
}
```

How to define the template depends a little on which version of Drupal you are using, but have a look at [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6) and [`theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/6) as a starting point.